# Policies and claims in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating an API and I have some questions regarding the claims / policies. Register policies with claims in development is relatively easy, I create a policy with X claims and add that policy to a controller / method and anyone who has those claims can access. The problem is:

1) How do I create a policy in production and give it permission to access a certain place? It's possible? Or the only thing I have to do is add X claims to a user and is that enough?

2) In the case that is enough, should create a table to store claims (only claims) to have a list of claims and then assign them to users (aspNetUserClaims table)?

3) If I create a role in production and assign claims and then assign that role to a user, with that is enough to access the controller / methods mentioned above? or when logging in, explicitly do I need to capture the claims of a role and add them to the user?

Thanks in advance! Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a user visit a website, the user got a set of claims. the claims belong to either roles or users. but a policy is a set of r**u**les, it has no any relationship with either roles or users. a policy is validated from any resources, not only the 2 claims tables, it depends on your code. here is a full example of Policy-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

> 1) How do I create a policy in production and give it permission to
>   access a certain place? It's possible? Or the only thing I have to do
>   is add X claims to a user and is that enough?

3 questions: Yes, Yes, No.

Since ClaimAuthorizeAttribute does not exist in Identity Framework, you have 2 options:

1. imeplement ClaimAuthorizeAttribute:
   https://github.com/jayway/JayLabs.Owin.OAuthAuthorization/blob/master/src/JayLabs.Owin.OAuthAuthorization/ClaimAuthorizeAttribute.cs
2. use `Policy` to apply Claims(Recommended by me).

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddAuthorization(options =>
       {
           options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy =>
           {
               policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
               {
                  //Here you can get many resouces from context, i get a claim here for example
                  var yourvalue = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "yourType")?.Value;
                  //here you can access DB or any other API to do anything if you don't mind performance issues.
                  var user = new DefaultContext().AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
                                               x.UserName == yourvalue);
                  //return a boolen to end validation.
                  return user != null;
              });
          });
      });
   }

   [Authorize(Policy = "EmployeeOnly")]
   public IActionResult VacationBalance()
   {
      return View();
   }
   ```

Here is a full solution to apply policies dynamically:
https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/creating-dynamic-authorization-policies-aspnet-core/

> 2) In the case that is enough, should create a table to store claims
>   (only claims) to have a list of claims and then assign them to users
>   (aspNetUserClaims table)?

Yes&No, you should have tables, but it's not assigned to users, but somewhere else where stores Policy requirements(It is `AspNetPolicyRequirement` in my following code).

> 3) If I create a role in production and assign claims and then assign
>   that role to a user, with that is enough to access the controller /
>   methods mentioned above? or when logging in, explicitly do I need to
>   capture the claims of a role and add them to the user?

2 questions: Yes, Yes.
Custom claims must be explicitly assigned to user for feature use on logging in, unless you want to access it from DB every time you need it.

Got back to your first question.

if you want to enable/disable a policy by conditions, it's very easy to do it from `database`.

Setps:

inject IHostingEnvironment first in `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment, ...)
    {
        _environment = environment;
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

then add following code in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
if (_environment.IsProduction())
        {
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
            });
        }
```

or

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    if (_environment.IsProduction())
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    }

});
```

The next step: there is no existing `AspNetUserPolicy` or `WhateverPolicy` tables right now, and I don't think it will exist in framework level. if your policies are only from claims, no any others, you can just use 2 claims tables to register policies, but I don't recommend it, because it's an anti-design of `Policy`.

Typically, it could be following design:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetPolicy]******/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetPolicy](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetPolicy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetPolicyRequirement]******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetPolicyRequirement](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AspNetPolicyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequirementType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequirementName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetPolicyRequirement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetPolicy] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AspNetPolicy_Enabled]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Enabled]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetPolicyRequirement] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AspNetPolicyRequirement_Enabled]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Enabled]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetPolicyRequirement]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetPolicyRequirement_AspNetPolicy] FOREIGN KEY([AspNetPolicyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetPolicy] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetPolicyRequirement] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetPolicyRequirement_AspNetPolicy]
GO
```

then your entities would be:

```
public partial class AspNetPolicy
{
    public AspNetPolicy()
    {
        AspNetPolicyRequirement = new HashSet<AspNetPolicyRequirement>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    [InverseProperty("AspNetPolicy")]
    public ICollection<AspNetPolicyRequirement> AspNetPolicyRequirement { get; set; }
}
public partial class AspNetPolicyRequirement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AspNetPolicyId { get; set; }
    public RequirementType RequirementType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string RequirementName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    [ForeignKey("AspNetPolicyId")]
    [InverseProperty("AspNetPolicyRequirement")]
    public AspNetPolicy AspNetPolicy { get; set; }
}
public enum RequirementType
{
    Custom = 0,
    Claim = 1,
    Role = 2,
    UserName = 3,
    AuthenticatedUser = 4,
    Assertion = 5,
}
```

To enable policies by following code:

```
private void ConfigurePolicies(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //get data by your way, here is only an example.
    var policies = new DefaultContext().AspNetPolicy
        .Include(x => x.AspNetPolicyRequirement)
        .Where(x => x.Enabled)
        .ToList();

    //map them to real policies
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        policies.ForEach(aspNetPolicy =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(aspNetPolicy.Name, policy =>
            {
                foreach (var aspNetPolicyRequirement in aspNetPolicy.AspNetPolicyRequirement.Where(x=>x.Enabled))
                {
                    switch (aspNetPolicyRequirement.RequirementType)
                    {
                        case RequirementType.Claim:
                        {
                            policy.RequireClaim(aspNetPolicyRequirement.RequirementName);
                            break;
                        }
                        case RequirementType.UserName:
                        {
                            policy.RequireUserName(aspNetPolicyRequirement.RequirementName);
                            break;
                        }
                        case RequirementType.Role:
                        {
                            policy.RequireRole(aspNetPolicyRequirement.RequirementName);
                            break;
                        }
                        case RequirementType.AuthenticatedUser:
                        {
                            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                            break;
                        }
                        case RequirementType.Assertion:
                        {
                            //policy.RequireAssertion(...);//To Do
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

you have to do the rest work by your own design.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great response, but I still do not understand something.
1)

`private void ConfigurePolicies (IServiceCollection services)
{
    // get data by your way, here is only an example.
    var policies = new DefaultContext (). AspNetPolicy
        .Include (x => x.AspNetPolicyRequirement)
        .Where (x => x.Enabled)
        .ToList ();

    // map them to real policies
    services.AddAuthorization (options =>
    {}
...
...
...
}`

Comment: As I understand it, this code is executed ONLY once when starting the API, is that correct? If this is correct, as it is possible that you can create Policies in production and also that they are registered for use.

Comment: 2) Assuming you create a policy in production, how do I use it? If for example I create the "CreateUserPolicy" policy and I want to use it in a controller, I should use it in the following way.

`[Authorize (Policy = "CreateUserPolicy")]
public class OneController {}`

Or in a method

`[Authorize (Policy = "CreateUserPolicy")]
public class OneMethod {}`

I do not understand how this is possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the 1st question: yes,  it execute on startup, but if you want to enable new added policy from database, it's impossible. but you can add requirements on existing policy, but configure policies to `RequireAssertion`, then you can access database to apply validate. but if you just want to call a function to validate something existing in database, you don't need my datatables, you just need a function, set policy as : `policy.RequireAssertion`

Comment: the 2nd question, if you want to apply a brand new policy to a deployed website by database, it will be hard, since policy is hard coded as attributes.